# Memory Error as a direct cause of a System Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, memory-management

I have a script that creates a table on the database and then reads the data into a dataframe in python. This dataframe is quite large with 10M rows.

Below is the query I use to create the dataframe:

```
query='''create table prim_sales ... '''
cursor.execute(query,strt,stp)
q="select * from prim_sales"
prim_sales=pd.read_sql(q,con)
```

While trying to read the data into the dataframe, I get the following error:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
MemoryError: 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ae84e0c7dc91> in <module>
    101 cursor.execute(query,strt,stp)
    102 q="select * from prim_sales"
--> 103 prim_sales=pd.read_sql(q,con)
    104 
    105 query='''CREATE TEMP TABLE prim_card AS

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    378             sql, index_col=index_col, params=params,
    379             coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 380             chunksize=chunksize)
    381 
    382     try:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
   1475                                         parse_dates=parse_dates)
   1476         else:
-> 1477             data = self._fetchall_as_list(cursor)
   1478             cursor.close()
   1479 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in _fetchall_as_list(self, cur)
   1484 
   1485     def _fetchall_as_list(self, cur):
-> 1486         result = cur.fetchall()
   1487         if not isinstance(result, list):
   1488             result = list(result)

SystemError: <class 'decimal.Decimal'> returned a result with an error set
```

Could someone please let me know what is going on and how to prevent it, if possible ?

Comment: Use 64-bit and buy more RAM. ;)

Comment: @qräbnö I am using 64-bit version. Before investing in RAM, I just wanted to know if it's because of something I am doing wrong!

Comment: I don't think you made a mistake (guess). If you don't have to load everything into RAM at once, but can process each of your 10 million lines individually or in blocks, you may have won. Take a look at LIMIT and OFFSET in SQL to do it block by block. I was in a similar situation at the time and didn't want to admit that I needed more RAM. In the end I developed my script on a box that had more RAM.

Comment: And find a way to monitor your RAM. Windows: [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [ESC]. If the blue line comes near the top edge of the graph, you've lost. Then all you have to do is restart. Mac: [Apple] + [Space], then "activity Monitor". Linux: `htop` or `free -g`.